# JpaRepository not making the connection to the local machine database instead of the docker container database

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I'm trying to use a docker container to run the tests of a springboot microservices application. The problem is that the application makes the connection to my machine instead of the docker container that holds the database.

This is my first time doing this so I'm guessing this is a configuration problem but, every time I look for instructions, it seems that the annotations `@Testcontainers` and `@Container` are enough to make sure springboot uses the container.

Here's my code:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ProductServiceApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Container
    static PostgreSQLContainer<?> postgreSQLContainer = new PostgreSQLContainer<>("postgres:12.13")
        .withDatabaseName("postgreSQLContainer")
        .withUsername("test")
        .withPassword("test");

    static void setProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry dynamicPropertyRegistry) {
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.url", postgreSQLContainer::getJdbcUrl);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.username", postgreSQLContainer::getUsername);
        dynamicPropertyRegistry.add("spring.datasource.password", postgreSQLContainer::getPassword);
    }

    @Test
    void shouldCreateProduct() throws Exception {

        ProductRequest productRequest = getProductRequest();
        String productRequestString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(productRequest);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/product")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(productRequestString)
            ).andExpect(status().isCreated()); //THIS IS OK
        
        Assertions.assertTrue(productRepository.findAll().size() == 1); //THIS FAILS
    }

    private ProductRequest getProductRequest() {
        return ProductRequest.builder()
            .name("some-product")
            .description("some-description")
            .price(BigDecimal.valueOf(10))
            .build();
    }

}
```

Debugging this issue I saw that the repository was hitting the postgresql database that I had local.
[image: [screenshot]]

And if I shotdown my local postgresql service this is what happens:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `@DynamicPropertySource` annotation on your `setProperties` method. Spring doesn't know that you are providing properties without this annotation.